# Why null was called "a subtype of every reference type"?

Tags: java, generics, null

Guys, could any one give a logical explanation of phrase I met in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0026OR2HM):

> You may find it helpful to think of `? extends T` as containing every type in an interval bounded by the type of `null` below and by `T` above (where **the type of `null` is a subtype of every reference type**).

Thanks.

Comment: Though not the part you're asking about, I'm not sure I like the statement "interval bounded by the type of null below and by T above" either. Since `null` can be cast to a reference of *any* type, I feel like it's even less "specific" than `T`, which would make the interval a little whacky...I guess I'm just nitpicking on the basis of my own (probably mathematically flawed) interpretation, though. :P

Comment: @Tim: Tim, I completely agree with you on this rather unintuitive logic, because saying "being a subclass" makes me thing of concrete and practical usage + real properties of type hierarchies & OOP stuff... See an article posted by @JRL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it just means that you can assign the null reference to any reference type. It doesn't strike me as a terribly helpful way of thinking about it.

The Java Language Specification has this to say about the null type (in [section 4.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html)):

> There is also a special null type, the
>   type of the expression null, which has
>   no name. Because the null type has no
>   name, it is impossible to declare a
>   variable of the null type or to cast
>   to the null type. The null reference
>   is the only possible value of an
>   expression of null type. The null
>   reference can always be cast to any
>   reference type. In practice, the
>   programmer can ignore the null type
>   and just pretend that null is merely a
>   special literal that can be of any
>   reference type.

Comment: so, the key phrase here is `The null reference can always be cast to any reference type`, this what makes auhthor to claim `the type of null is a subtype of every reference type`. Weird one :) Thanks for pointing this.

Comment: It's a helpful way of thinking insofar as it tells you that Java's type system is unsound, which in turn makes it pretty much useless.

Answer (score 2):

Types form a partial order, i.e. for any two types in the set of all types in the program, there might be a relation between them (i.e. `T1 < T2` - T2 is a subtype of T1 in some sense).  Things in unrelated class hierarchies have no such relation defined.

So basically what this is telling you is that all members of the set of types that `? extends T` describes is less than `T` and greater than `null`.  null exists as a subtype of everything because it is always valid to assign the value `null` to a reference.

More formally:

```
∀x ∈ ? extends T. null ≥ x ≥ T
```

Answer (score 2):

From [this interesting article](http://blogs.oracle.com/abuckley/entry/naming_the_null_type), an excerpt:

> Java has the null type. Pre-JLS3, the
>   null type was not officially the
>   subtype of any type, and the null
>   reference was not officially a value
>   of any type except the null type. A
>   decree made the null reference
>   castable to any reference type for
>   pragmatic reasons. (This is similar to
>   the decree that makes List
>   assignable to a List formal
>   parameter even though List is not a
>   subtype of List. You know the
>   decree as capture conversion.) JLS3
>   defines the null type as a subtype of
>   every type, so it looks an awful lot
>   like Bottom.

Comment: Appreciate a lot your elaboraton of the topic. I wasn't aware of that monster null type.

Comment: If you know Scala, the type of Java's `null` is similar to the Scala type `Nothing`, which is a subtype of all reference types (all types that are subtypes of `AnyRef`).

Answer (score 0):

That means that null can be any type.

You might have a class `Animal` with a subclass `Dog`.
If you have a variable of type `Animal` with the value `null` you can not tell if the `null` is of type `Animal` or type `Dog`. Both are equally valid.

Comment: I think that's a slightly deceptive statement.  The value `null` always has exactly one type - the type `null`.  It cannot be "any type".  The type system defines the type `null` (which is only inhabited by the value `null`) to be a sub-type of all reference types. In your example, this is as though you had an implied `null` class defined as a sub-class of `Animal`, and therefore it would be valid to assign the value `null` (an instance of this `null` class) to a variable of type `Animal`.

Answer (score -1):

```
null instanceof T
```

is true for any type T.

Comment: how about `System.out.println(null instanceof Object);` giving `false`?

Comment: Thats completely not true.  Java creators went out of their way to make that case always false

Comment: I am embarassed.  I just assumed!